# Посоветуйте плагин WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Пожалуйста посоветуйте плагин для авторизации через социальные сети для WordPress, чтобы была хорошая совместимость с плагинами доски объявлений Directorist если кто знает ну или просто хороший плагин и желательно бесплатный

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно не плохой плагин, по совместимости не подскажу но у плагина есть шорткоды что делает возможность запихнуть авторизацию через соц сети практически в любое место

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/

Comment: Пасиба большое.